# select some records from table using IN keyword

Tags: sql

I want to select some records from table using `IN` keyword, where parameter under `IN` keyword are `Varchar` type as concatenated value of Id using "," where as Id is int type

```
select UserId, Name from UserMaster WHERE UserId IN ('1,2,3,4,5')
```

Thank you

Comment: Friendly suggestion: Normalize your table. Get rid of comma-separated fields.

Comment: @ypercube I think the table is normalized. The problem looks like that @jeetendra gets an inputstring from somewhere and puts that string directly in a query

Comment: @Ocaso: My bad. Then @dpmattingly's answer is correct.

Comment: I know that this is a duplicate, because I remember to have seen many similar questions. The problem, though, is that this particular kind of questions is hard to find using SO's built-in search, because it seems to just ignore the 'in' word.

Answer (score 5):

You need to separate the strings that you're searching for. Right now, instead of searching for five different strings, you're searching for one string: "1,2,3,4,5"

```
select UserId, Name from UserMaster WHERE UserId IN ('1','2','3','4','5')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strString = "1,2,3,4,5"

select UserId, Name from UserMaster WHERE (UserId IN ("&strString&"))
```